# SonarQube/ANT Authentication required for 'svn+ssh://

Tags: java, ant, sonarqube, svnkit, sonarqube-scan

Using fresh installed **SonarQube 5.6**, my ANT scanner complains `svn: E170001: Authentication required for 'svn+ssh://my-server'` while getting author (blame) data.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java" ... build.sonar.xml
[...shortened]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error when executing blame for file /path/to/foo.java
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:116)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    [...shortened]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error when executing blame for file /path/to/foo.java
    at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand.blame(SvnBlameCommand.java:102)
    [...shortened]
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException: svn: E170001: Authentication required for 'svn+ssh://my-server'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.authenticationFailed(SVNErrorManager.java:47)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.authenticationFailed(SVNErrorManager.java:41)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager.getFirstAuthentication(DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager.java:203)
```

SonarQube-5.6 installation seems fine, I installed Java/JSON plugins as admin before first scan.

- My code is obviously hosted at `svn+ssh://my-server/path/to/root`. There, `svnadmin --version` says `Version 1.5.7 (r36142)`
- IP of  `my-server` is in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` (I
  contact the server through a tunnel and my-server has no DNS entry)
- putty session named `my-server` connects successfully.
- `svn up` works fine via TortoiseSVN v1.9.4 UI and command line and Intellij IDEA.

  - I have cached my SVN credentials. No pwd prompt when `svn up`

I use

- win10 x64
- JDK jdk1.8.0_51 (running ANT/build/sonarqube-ant-task-2.4.1.jar)
- JRE version "1.8.0_91" (running SonarQube)

I had cleared my `C:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Roaming\Subversion` and rentered the pwd.

**Any ideas how to get tmatesoft's SVNKit to use my cached authentication data? Thanks a lot!**

Comment: http://wiki.svnkit.com/Authentication#SSL_Manager says "On Windows machines name\password credentials are often stored encrypted. Unfortunately, SVNKit is not able to decrypt such credentials, therefore they are not used (just skipped)"

Why didn't I have this ith SQ-5.4 on my old Win7? Reading rel notes from SQ-5.5 or SQ-5.6 I cannot see SVNKit is new.

Answer (score 0):

Passing `-Dsvnkit.ssh2.key=path/to/private/key` pointing to an OpenSSH formatted private key file helped. I pass it as jvm arg to my ANT that runs the build.xml containing the `<sonar>` target.

By playing with SVNKit 1.8.12 standalone, logging enabled, I found the complaint about the private key file format.

Now, my scanner runs sucessfully for the first time.

Notably, not passing the correct property value **now** does **not** break the scan any more, just a small complaint about missing blame data. But I won't investgate that.